# Objective-c iOS 5.x - Check if the iDevice is connected to a computer

Tags: objective-c

I want to check if an iOS device is currently connected to a computer (Wifi And Cable)

I tried to [google it](http://www.google.com/search?&q=Xcode%20check%20if%20iphone%20is%20syncing%20-connected) and looked into the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/), but couldn't seem to find anything related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is physically connected you can check the battery state, like so:

```
UIDeviceBatteryState myBatteryState = [UIDevice currentDevice].myBatteryState;
if (myBatteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging) {
    //code
} else if (myBatteryState == UIDeviceBatteryStateFull) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: This will only work when syncing with a cable , not WiFi Sync.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you meant physically connected. That's a good question, I'd be curious to know myself. Good luck!

Comment: actually, just for completeness, if you are looking for the physical cable connection (that's what I thought he meant, too), you also need to check for the state `UIDeviceBatteryStateFull`.  once the battery's charged, but still connected via cable, the status will be full.

Comment: this does not answer the question, this code will also work when the iphone is plugged into a charger. This is technically wrong.